# How to run gradle build manually on a flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter

Currently, I am getting "**Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**" while trying to build a Flutter project (flutter run). The logs do not help much. Therefore, i want to run "**gradlew build**" or similar manually with stacktrace option to see what is happening under the hood. What is the command for that ?

Comment: please paste the whole error log here

Comment: @JayMungara, That is what I am trying to achive. To get whole error logs. if you know command to build project using gradle. Please paste here.

Comment: In your flutter project there are 2 folders, ios & android. Open the terminal and go in the android folder. If you're on OSX or Linux you can then type in the terminal ```./gradlew build``` or ```./gradlew assembleDebug```. The later command will try to create an apk. Also if you're using Android Studio, in the project structure, you can open the android folder, and open the ```AndroidManifest.xml```. AS will ask you if you want to open the android project into a new window, open it and run it as a normal android project.

Comment: `cd android` and `.\gradlew build`

Comment: @danypata Many Thanks. Yes I had to be inside the Android folder. Many Thanks

Comment: try `flutter build -v ...`

Comment: @danypata Many Thanks. Yes I had to be inside the Android folder. Many Thanks. As you were first to comment, kindly answer the question. I ll vote you up.

Answer (score 17):

For posterity I will post my comment as an answer too and I'll elaborate it a bit.

When you create a flutter project there are two new folders created inside the main folder, one is `android` and one is `ios`.

The `android` folder contains the Android native code and all the android configurations, you can handle it as a native android project.

The `ios` folder contains the iOS native code and all the ios configurations, it also has the `xcworkspace` file which can be opened with Xcode like a normal ios project.

Now you can run platform specific commands in each folder, like i said, the folders contain actual native projects.

So for Android you could do:

```
    cd android/
    ./gradlew clean
    ./gradlew build
```

(clean and build the project)

For iOS you could do:

```
   cd ios/
   pod repo update
   pod install
```

(update the pod repo and install the pods)

Just a short reminder, if you want to create apk/ipa from the native folders, don't forget to run `flutter build` in the main folder, otherwise you might get outdated code in your apk/ipa.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the folder where you have gradle installed(the place where your GRADLE_HOME variable points to).
   [image: Folder where my gradle is installed]
2. Move inside the wrapper folder
   [image: Pointing an arrow towards the gradle wrapper folder]
3. Move inside the dists folder which is inside the wrapper folder
   [image: Gradle dists folder inside the wrapper folder]
4. Delete everything that you can find inside the dists folder(cached gradle wrapper)
   [image: Content of gradle dists folder]
5. Run/launch your android flutter project again. It should re-download the gradle wrapper and if you don't have any connection problems your project should run correctly.

Note: I'm having the same problem because of my unstable internet connection. I'm ending up with a corrupted gradle wrapper file and the download doesn't restart.

6. If the download gets interrupted and fails to completely download and launch your project repeat all of the steps.