# Build Android Flutter project with gradlew command

Tags: jenkins, gradle, flutter, build

I have configured my Jenkins server to build Android app. Jenkins Gradle plugin executes `gradlew` command to build my project. Now I want to add Flutter project to my Jenkins. Can Flutter project be built by `gradlew` command, just like any other Android project, rather than by `flutter` command? I want to build arm32 apk and bundle. Are there gradle tasks to build them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run gradle build manually on a flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911463/how-to-run-gradle-build-manually-on-a-flutter-project)

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
gradlew build --info
```

on Android folder.